# Equivalent Definition of Continuity

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I am trying to understand a proof in a book. (Willard, General Topology, p. 45)

**Theorem**: Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces and $f : X \to Y$. If for each $E \subseteq X$, $f(\operatorname{Cl}_X(E)) \subseteq \operatorname{Cl}_Y f(E)$, then $f$ is continuous on $X$.

**Proof**: Let $x \in X$ and let $V$ be an open neighborhood of $f(x)$. Set $E = X - f^{-1}(V)$ and let $U = X - \operatorname{Cl}_X E$. It is easy to verify that, since $f(\operatorname{Cl}_X E) \subseteq \operatorname{Cl}_Y f(E)$, we have $x \in U$. It is even clearer that $f(U) \subseteq V$. Hence $f$ is continuous at $x$.

I have not been able to show that $x \in U$ and $f(U) \subseteq V$.

**Scratch Work**:
For the first part, if I suppose by way of contradiction that $x \notin U$, then $x \in \operatorname{Cl}_X E$ and by hypothesis $f(x) \in \operatorname{Cl}_Y f(E) = \bigcap\{K$ closed in $Y : f(E) \subseteq K\}$. But $f(E) \subseteq Y - V$ which is closed. So $f(x) \in Y - V$ which means $x \notin f^{-1}(V)$ which means $x \in E$. But then $x \notin f^{-1}(V)$, a contradiction since $f(x) \in V$. Is this correct? I am unable to get anywhere with the second part ($f(U) \subseteq V$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have shown that $x\in U$. That was the hard part. Now, to show that $f(U)\subseteq V$, consider any point $u\in U$; you have to show that $f(u)\in V$. The fact that $u\in U=X-\operatorname{Cl}_XE$ means that $u\notin\operatorname{Cl}_XE$. Since $E\subseteq\operatorname{Cl}_XE$, that also means that $u\notin E=X-f^{-1}(V)$, so $u\in f^{-1}(V)$, i.e., $f(u)\in V$.